# What implants are available to increase researching ability?

Tags: neocron

I've recently started playing Neocron, because Reakktor has just launched a new server called Titan.  I'm playing with some friends, and I am making a researching alt spy to identify my unidentified tech parts.

I have noticed there are some implants that increase researching, like Advanced Nerves 3 and the like, but was wondering if there is a complete list of all implants that increase researching.  I'm also wondering how much researching I will need to reliably research these parts without failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that researching in Neocron works, is that you need *at least* the same amount of skill points in the researching skill as the tech level of what you're trying to research, but until you have double the tech level in research there is always a possibility of failing the research. The more research you have, the less chance of failing.

For example, if you're trying to research a TL90 item, you need to have *at least* 90 skill points in researching, but require 180 or more before you're guaranteed not to fail the researching process. The possibly outcomes of failure range from simply 'failing', to destroying the item you were trying to research, so it's always better to have as much researching as possible.

There is a good item database over at [techhaven.org](http://www.techhaven.org/db/) which contains detail on every item in the game and where you can get it from.

Specifically for researching, there are the following implants:

**[Brain Implants](http://www.techhaven.org/db/implants/brain)**

- Tech Haven CPU: +9.91 research
- Special Sciences CPU: +7.86 research
- Area MC5 Hawking CPU: +10.45 research

**[Backbones](http://www.techhaven.org/db/implants/backbones)**

- Advanced Nerves v1: +2.4 research
- Advanced Nerves v2: +4.13 research
- Advanced Nerves v3: +5.92 research

**[Tradeskill Gloves](http://www.techhaven.org/db/implants/gloves/tradeskill)**

- Machina Research Glove: +13.92 research

This means that with the best available implants in the game, it is possible to get +48.06 to your research from implants. In addition to implants there is a drug called 'Blue Fairy' available from the Black Dragon Faction Supply Manager which adds an additional +9.06 research for five minutes.

For more information on researching, there is a [guide to being a researcher](http://www.techhaven.org/resources/tradeskill-guides/researching-guide.html) on the techhaven.org website.